# What is the equivalent of hg clone --noupdate in git?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, equivalent, version-control-migration

We got a whole system using `hglib` for quite some time and we're creating an abstraction layer to customize some needs of the system, but I'm having trouble understanding an equivalent of

`hg clone source destination --noupdate` **in Git**

`-U   --noupdate  the clone will include an empty working directory (only a repository)`

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/clone

Thank you in advances.

Comment: Not precisely the same (well, not the same at all really: it's ever so much klunkier) but consider `git clone --bare`.

Comment: @torek what about `git clone --no-checkout`? Is it no the same?

Comment: `git clone --no-checkout` is definitely closer to `hg clone -U`. Which to use depends on what you plan to do with the resulting repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of web browsing, found a good equivalent:

```
git clone --no-checkout
```

My use case:

We wanted a bare clone of some sort, the way `--noupdate` flag does for HG.

Technically speaking, in git I guess it would be jut cloning without checking out on it.

If someone else has a good answer, please you're welcome to edit this answer.

Comment: Do you want to have a bare clone (one without working copy at all, `git clone --bare`)